# how to move from main page to next page in Selenium to extract full information of posts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to extract posts from this URL “https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts”/. To extract the full text of posts, I write a code to click on each post, extract the body, and then back to the previous page to click on the next post… but it works just for the first post.

```
y= 1
lst_post = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]')
for post in lst_post:
    add = post.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div['+ str(y)+ ']/a').click()
    #add_convert=add.replace('.', '^')
    time.sleep(3)
    post_body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
    like_count = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.post-action--like')
    print (post_body.text)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(3)
    y = y+1
```

Comment: This won't work because the element becomes stale when the dom changes. Try getting the hrefs and iterating those instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off when we get the webpage we scroll and then click to get the two elements out of the way. You can then retrieve all the hrefs of the a tags. Loop through them and then print it's text. The ascii is for the **'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 132-132: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk** error you will get trying to parse the whole page which translates into it's ascii value.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,300);")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ccc-notify-accept"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".floating-box-sign-up__dismiss.icon-close"))).click()
lst_post = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='results-post']/a")]
for lst in lst_post:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(lst)
    post_body = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")))
    like_count = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".post-action--like")))
    print (ascii(post_body.text))
    print(like_count.text)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used your suggestion but I had this error  "NameError: name 'wait' is not defined".  Then I tried to replace wait with "WebDriverWait(driver, 10)...." but then I have another system errors "File "C:\Users\thmag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))

NameError: name '_element_if_visible' is not defined"

Comment: Did you include the imports at the top.

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3) also this

Comment: yes, I did it but I got this error : "
  File "C:\Users\thmag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))

NameError: name '_element_if_visible' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You're find elements is only returing the parent div. You want to select all the divs under that.
Use this xpath:

```
/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div
```

and then you'll loop through the elements.

Or an even better (less brittle) xpath would be:

```
//div[@class='results-post']
```

So use this xpath in your line:

```
lst_post = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class='results-post']')
for post in lst_post:
```

Comment: Many thanks, I did what you said. the code extracts the first post but for the second one there is an error for this line command "post.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div['+ str(y)+ ']').click()"     
And the error is " File "C:\Users\thmag\HealthUnlockSelenium\login.py", line 69, in <module>
    post.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div['+ str(y)+ ']').click()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'"